# Is "傷" a subset of "怪我"?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to clarify the differences between `傷{きず}` and `怪我{けが}`. Are these assertions correct?

> - `傷` is used exclusively for minor cuts and abrasions to the skin?
> - `怪我` can also be used for cuts and abrasions, as well as bruising or other minor injuries. `怪我` is also used for major injuries such as broken bones, concussions, etc?

So, calling any type of injury a `怪我` is technically correct. And, using `怪我` allows you to say `怪我した。`

Using `傷` allows you to be more specific as to the type of injury, but then you must say something like `傷がついた。`

My strategy is to always say `怪我する` because I don't need to worry about sensing the distinction between `傷` and `怪我`, and I like how `怪我する` sounds. Is this a good policy? Is it ever critical that I say `傷` instead of `怪我`?

Comment: Hum, I can think of a case: when talking about an object (often screens) that has scratches, I think you can only use 傷. I guess that your question only concerns humans though !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

傷 refers to damaged skin/surface resulting mainly 
from an injury, and 怪我 refers to injury itself. While, by its nature, 傷 does not usually refer to life-threatening injuries, I don't think 傷 is a strict subset of 怪我.

- 腕に傷がある: OK
- 腕に怪我がある: Understandable, but slightly unnatural to me
- 昔の傷: An old scar
- 昔の怪我: (refers to an old event rather than a scar)
- 怪我をする: OK
- 傷をする: Wrong

Comment: I think it is better to use "injury" than the word "trauma", which has other connotations. (In normal British English it is essentially never used to mean simply "injury".)

Comment: I think I get it. Could i ever say "怪我は大丈夫ですか" or "怪我が治りましたか"?

Comment: @BrianChandler Thank you, is it better now?

Comment: @david There is little difference between 怪我が治る and 傷が治る, or 怪我の状態 and 傷の状態, as long as traumatic skin injury is concerned.

Comment: I would avoid the word "trauma"; although it is a technical medical word, the normal term is "injury" (I cannot really speak American, but I believe "injury" is universal.) Particularly, "traumatic event" means 「悪夢のような出来事」, and "traumatic injury" is repetive, and should just be "injury".

Comment: @BrianChandler OK, I've been familiar with [traumatic injury as a medical term](http://www.traumaticbraininjury.com/understanding-tbi/what-is-traumatic-brain-injury/) (it specifically refers to physical injury as opposed to electric/chemical injury or burns), but didn't know it sounds odd in normal conversations.

Comment: 他にも「手術の傷」はOKでも、「手術の怪我」はダメという例もありますね。

Comment: Quite coincidentally I just had an accident that both broke, and cut, my hand... "昨日、左手を怪我した。傷もあるし、骨も折れた。" Thereafter, I can just say "骨" and the listener knows I mean the broken one. I'd think that'd be how to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be more specific you could also use:

#### Serious injury

- 大怪我{おおけが} — more casual
- 重傷{じゅうしょう} - more formal

#### Light injury

- かすり傷{きず} -  more casual
- 軽傷{けいしょう} - more formal

To my understanding, both 傷 and 怪我 are very general terms and don't really say much about the magnitude of damage. I think it's correct that 傷 is used for more for cuts and damage to the skin, while 怪我 has a broader usage, and can be used for pretty much any type of injury. 傷 is also used in some other words/verbs like scars and hurt feelings, 傷跡 and 傷つく.

On the news they use 軽傷 and 重傷 a lot, but I've also heard 大怪我 and things like 軽い/重い or 怪我/傷.

**Also be careful about the usage of *傷つく* since that verb is often used with [hurt feelings/emotions](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AE%E5%82%B7).**

傷を負う may be better if you are talking about getting hurt and want to use 傷, but a native speaker can probably clarify that.

For broken bones 骨折する is also often used.

Another word that you probably hear a lot on the news is [傷害](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/+%E5%82%B7%E5%AE%B3%E3%82%92) which seems to mean just "injury" or "damage".